# Помогите решить задачу по СИ

Tags: c++, c

Даны строки A и B. Если в A есть повторяющиеся символы, а в B нет повторяю-
щихся символов, то упорядочить символы B в алфавитном порядке и удалить латин-ские буквы из A; в остальных случаях упорядочить символы B в порядке, обратном к алфавитному, удалив повторяющиеся символы, и продублировать в A символы, не входящие в B.

Есть мысли как ее решить?

Comment: Задачу надо решить на си или java? У вас в теге java указан.

Comment: @AsadGaniev си,исправлю

Comment: Разбейте задачу на подзадачи. Вам нужно научиться: a) проверять наличие дубликатов, б) сортировать, в) фильтровать г) добавлять символы в строках. Потом все это собрать вместе

Comment: А в чем проблема? Проверяйте наличие повторяющихся символов в А, потом - в В. Потом, в зависимости от... Что именно вам неясно?

Comment: примерно так
bool duplicate = false;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) 
{
    if(a[i] == a[i+1])
    {duplicate = true; 
    break;}
 }

Comment: но это после сортировки массива A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз можно на С++ (тэг говорит, что можно):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

bool hasDouble(string s)
{
    sort(s.begin(),s.end());
    return unique(s.begin(),s.end()) != s.end();
}

int main()
{
    string a, b;
    cout << "a: ";
    getline(cin,a);
    cout << "b: ";
    getline(cin,b);

    if (hasDouble(a) && !hasDouble(b))
    {
        sort(b.begin(),b.end());
        a.erase(remove_if(a.begin(),a.end(),[](char x){ return isalpha(x); }),a.end());
    }
    else
    {
        sort(b.begin(),b.end(),greater<char>());
        b.erase(unique(b.begin(),b.end()),b.end());
        string s;
        for(auto c: a)
        {
            s += c;
            if (b.find(c) == string::npos) s += c;
        }
        a = s;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
}
```